# What happens if you see what you believe is an error in the French Language meta information?

Tags: discussion

Welcome to the question and answer site about the French language!

I think that is not phrased properly. I would phrase it: Welcome to the site for questions and answers about the French language.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. This is the right place. You're referring to the sentence in [/help](/help), right? That part of the page can be edited by moderators, I'll just give a bit of time for others to give their opinion.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Lambie Yours sounds better imho. How do you think _welcome to the French language Q&A website_ fares in comparison?

Comment: @Gilles On va sans doute rire, mais l'image du _union jack_, elle est plus large que celle du tricolore ?

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Oui, elles ont la même hauteur mais pas la même largeur. Je pense que c'est mieux comme ça que d'avoir la même largeur et des hauteurs différentes, ou d'avoir la même surface et des dimensions différentes, ou de ne pas respecter les proportions (eh oui, les proportions ne sont pas les mêmes, d'où le problème), mais on peut en discuter.

Comment: Welcome to the French language Q&A forum.

Comment: SE sites are [explicitly not forums](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/1014587). What do you think of the current title? "Bienvenue sur le site de questions-réponses sur la langue française !"

Comment: @Mast You seem to be on my case. Allow me to inform you that I was fixing the English grammar more than anything else. Welcome to the French language Q & A **site**. The link says: not a **help** forum. So, the word forum is not the issue. The real issue is the word **help**.

Comment: I'm referring to your last comment before mine.